# The p-adic expansion has repeating digits

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I read somewhere that if the p-adic expansion of a p-adic number has repeating digits from some point on if and only if the p-adic number is a rational number.

I wanted to test this with the 2-adic number $a=1+2+4+8+16+\cdots$. According to the above, $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ and we have \begin{array}{rcl}a=\dfrac{1}{1-2}=-\dfrac{1}{2}.\end{array}

However, when I multiply this with the 2-adic number $-2$ I don't get $1$. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: What you did wrong was $1-2=-2$.

Comment: I don't follow. You are saying that I should have written $\frac{1}{-2}$, right? But I still should get $1$ if I multiply this with $-2$.

Comment: Please, just check your arithmetic. Your displayed equation is wrong.

Comment: My apologies, very silly of me. When I correct my mistake I get $a=-1\in \mathbb{Q}$ which agrees with the statement above. Thanks.